# Performance hit on compiling code in virtual machine

Tags: compilation, virtual-machine

Is compiling code with GCC (for example, the Linux Kernel) on a Linux virtual machine running on top of Windows 7 significantly slower than native build box? I have a 6 core (FX6300), 8GB machine that I need to run Windows 7. I rather run Ubuntu but I need a Windows machine.

I am hoping that through some hardware virtualization magic, the raw power of the CPU and the RAM are accessible that the cost of compiling code in a virtual environment is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This of course depends strongly on the virtual machine software, but on a modern CPU and modern VM software supporting hardware virtualization, the penalty is pretty negligible.

Your CPU supports AMD-V hardware virtualization, so all you need is a suitable VM software that can utilize AMD-V. The free VirtualBox appears to support it, for example, but it tends to be slower for e.g. graphics. That won't matter for compilation speeds though.

Comment: Can you recommend a virtual machine software? VirtualBox is an obvious choice because of the price. I don't mind paying for something however.